# react native password autofill ios 11

Tags: ios, react-native, passwords, autofill

I've done some research but, at the time of writing, I cannot find any way of a React Native app integrating with the new iOS 11 password autofilling system.

Do we need to use entitlement certificates (as mentioned here: [Password AutoFill for iOS App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45032994/password-autofill-for-ios-app) and https://willowtreeapps.com/ideas/password-autofill-in-ios-11)

The part I'm not sure is how that integrates with React Native?!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Unfortunately this requires React Native's `TextInput` to bridge the native `UITextContentType`. The good news is that there is an open pull request that will add this functionality:

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/18526

Once merged, you can support the password auto-fill like so:

```
<TextInput
    value={this.state.username}
    textContentType="username"
/>
<TextInput
    value={this.state.password}
    secureTextEntry={true}
    textContentType="password"
/>
```

Comment: i seem to recall you have to link your app to your websites URL order for iOS to be confident that its displaying the right password. I am currently able to get the password bar to show up, however it is blank since iOS doesnt seem to have the information to be willing to offer to fill the password for the web service in the app.

Comment: my bad. the second article that the OP linked said that there needs to be a file placed on the server listing associated apps. https://willowtreeapps.com/ideas/password-autofill-in-ios-11

Comment: This has now been merged in, and is available! 